# Where to store selected list of elements?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have some lists of elements:

```
let list1 = [1,2,3,4]; 
let list2 = [1,2,3,4]; 
let list3 = [1,2,3,4];
```

I iterate each other in loop:

```
<div *ngFor="let el of list1" (click)="set(el)">{{el}</div>
<div *ngFor="let el of list2" (click)="set(el)">{{el}</div>
<div *ngFor="let el of list3" (click)="set(el)">{{el}</div>
```

When I click over element `<div>` I have to store selected value somewhere like this:

```
selectedFilters = {list1: [1], list2: [2,3], list3: [4]}
```

How to do that? Should I create a three models class:

```
class FilterSetter {
   set();
   unset();
}

class FilterList1 extends FilterSetter {
    selected = [];
}

class FilterList2 extends FilterSetter {
   selected = [];
}

class FilterList3 extends FilterSetter {
    selected = [];
}
```

I dont like my solution, because it forced me to create a lot of classed if lists will be added in the future.

Also I need get ouput json with all selected elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, add another param to your `set` something like source to know from which source the data came from.

EDIT: try not to use `set` as a name, use `addSelectedElem`

```
mySelectedElems: {
    list1: [];
    list2: [];
    list3: [];
}; // if you know already the names of the list. idk

addSelectedElem(elem, source) {
    mySelectedElems[source] = mySelectedElems[source] || []
    mySelectedElems[source].push(elem)
}
```

Comment: So, where to place this code? I dont mess component, because it should only display data.

Comment: selectedFilters where should it be stored ?

Comment: In service Angular, I try to move all responsibility to service

Comment: it is a little bit haedcoded to pass name of collection